# How to automatically set PDF 'Activity Subject' from template subject?

Tags: templates, pdf

Is it possible to automatically set the 'Activity Subject' of PDF letters to the 'Message Subject' of the selected template? I swear I've seen this done with a quick bit of code, but the keywords are escaping me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tracked this one down. It worked out of the box in 4.4.x, but doesn't in 4.5.x. Not sure whether it was deliberate, but it's pretty easy to 'fix'.

Edit templates/CRM/Mailing/Form/InsertTokens.tpl and change:

```
  cj.post( dataUrl, {tid: val}, function( data ) {
    if ( !isPDF ) {
      if (prefix == "SMS") {
          text_message = "sms_text_message";
      }
      else {
        cj("#subject").val( data.subject );
      }
```

to:

```
  cj.post( dataUrl, {tid: val}, function( data ) {
    cj("#subject").val( data.subject );
    if ( !isPDF ) {
      if (prefix == "SMS") {
          text_message = "sms_text_message";
      }
```

It's explicitly only setting the Activity Subject for non-PDFs, which is weird. It looks like it was [accidentally(?) reverted](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/1e035d58875c61cef9136fd8200dcef7fe591afe#diff-5990409ef24052bbfef770f424294b5cL151) when SMS support for recurring contributions was being added. Have created [an issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16211).

Comment: Issue is now patched and closed - should be part of 4.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use hook_civicrm_pre. But i'm not sure you have the template in this context.

```
function myextension_civicrm_pre( $op, $objectName, $id, &$params ) {
  if ($op == 'create' && $objectName == 'Activity') {
    // define PDFLETTER_ACTIVITY_ID or replace with the good id
    if ($objectRef->
    $params['activity_type_id'] == PDFLETTER_ACTIVITY_ID) {
      // 1. get the template (is it possible from there ?)      
      ...

      // 2. replace the title
      $params['subject'] = ...
    }

  }
}
```

Otherwise you will have to use hook_civicrm_postProcess but it's more complex.